# C++ get length from two dimensional dynamic array

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I have got stuck by the C++ two dimensional dynamic array. I want to get the array length.  Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int dosomestuff(char **dict);
int main(){
    int x, y;
    char **dict;  
    cin>>x>>y;    // here to input the 'x'
    dict = new char *[x];
    for(i = 0; i < x; i++){
        dict[i] = new char[y];
        for(j = 0; j < y; j++){
            cin>>dict[i][j];
        }
    }
    dosomestuff(dict);
}
int dosomestuff(char **dict){
    int x, y;
    x = sizeof(*dict);     //8 not equal to the 'x'
                           //run in mac_64  I think this is the pointer's length
    y = strlen(dict[0]);   //this equal to the 'y' in function main
    cout<<x<<" "<<y<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What I want is in function dosomestuff to get the x equal the 'x' in function main.

How can I to get it? Can anybody help me ~? Thx a lot.

Comment: Use some kind of `Matrix` class that tells you the size and cleans up the memory (which you don't).

Comment: Is there any simple function like 'sizeof' to get the length? Cause I need this to solve a data-structure question.

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator. And once you convert it to a pointer, the size is gone.

Comment: `dict[0]` is the same as `*dict`

Comment: Oh, here I use the strlen(dict[0])  to get the length, forgot to change it. Thx for your notice.  @MattMcNabb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(*dict)` only gives you the `sizeof(char*)`, which is not what you are hoping for.

There is no way of knowing the value of `x` from `dict` in `dosomestuff`. If you want to use `char**` for `dict`, your best option is to pass `x` and `y` to `dosomestuff`.

```
int dosomestuff(char **dict, int x, int y);
```

Since you are using C++, you can use:

```
std::vector<std::string> dict;
```

Then you would have all the information you need in `dosomestuff` if you pass that `dict` to it.

Comment: Didn't even notice the bottom type was `char`. Good catch.

Comment: @RSahu Forgot to thank you. = = I am a rookie in c++. Thx for your help ~ : )